# Jakson mapper deserlize null properties if not matches found

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Hello I am trying to return null object if the response is not relevant to the object.
Example:

- I send a request and I receive Status code 400 bad request
- Deserialize the response to and POJO class
- After Deserialize, all properties are null or default value for integers

This is my mapper configs:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
```

This is how I use the mapper:

```
 POJO pojo = mapper.readValue(response.body().string(), POJO.class);
```

This is my Class to Deserialize:

```
@Getter
public class POJO {
    public Object name;
    public String someString;
 }
```

And I receive `POJO(name=null, someString=null)`

Simple response:

```
{  "error": {    "status": 400,    "message": "invalid id"  }}
```

I need the POJO Class to be null if this is the response. Sorry for bad explanation, I am new to Jackson.

Comment: Generally, you would look at the response status rather than assuming the response is valid. If the response status isn't 200, then deserialize as an error object so you can log the error and then return null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read POJO response only and only when valid response status received - normally `HTTP/1.1 200 Ok`. In other cases - read it as a error response:

```
@Getter
class ErrorStatus {
    int status;
    String message;
}

@Getter
class ErrorResponse {
    ErrorStatus error;
}

if (response.status().code() != 200) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = mapper.readValue(response.body().string(), ErrorResponse.class);
    System.out.println("error: " + errorResponse);
    return;
}

POJO pojo = mapper.readValue(response.body().string(), POJO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to return a null object when deserializing a JSON response that does not match the POJO class.

Here is some code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);

String responseBody = response.body().string();
POJO pojo = null;

try {
    pojo = mapper.readValue(responseBody, POJO.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    // Handle exception if needed
}


if (pojo == null) {
    pojo = new POJO();
}
```

This way, if the JSON response does not contain properties that match the POJO class, the resulting POJO object will have all its properties set to null, as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi I think you misunderstand my question current implementation initialize POJO class with null values or default for boolean and int I want to return POJO null if the response is not mapped.Thanks